# how to animate a button inside a LinearLayout with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android

I'm tryng to animate a Button inside a LinearLayout with ObjectAnimator and when i click on the Layout nothing happens.

But if i change buttons by ImageViews inside the LinearLayout the animation starts with no problems.

Heres is xml:

```
<LinearLayout        
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"         
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code:

```
final LinearLayout images = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.images);
    images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            final ObjectAnimator goneToVisible = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(images, "rotationY", -90f, 0f);
            goneToVisible.setDuration(1000);
            goneToVisible.start();
        }
    });
```

Everthing works fine but when i change ImageView by Button:

```
<LinearLayout        
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"         
        android:background="@drawable/image1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />          
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/image2"
        android:visibility="gone" />        
</LinearLayout>

final LinearLayout images = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.images);
    images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //flip(image1, image2, animLength.getProgress());
            final ObjectAnimator goneToVisible = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(images, "rotationY", -90f, 0f);
            goneToVisible.setDuration(1000);
            goneToVisible.start();
        }
    });
```

animation is not working.

If a take out button from LinearLayout it works but not inside. I need to use Buttons instead ImageView.

How can i solve the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code with `ImageView` work for you because the `ImageView`  is not clickable by default so when you click on `LinearLayou` the click event will respond for the `LinearLayout` and the  animation in layout click event will work

The second code with `Button` doesn't work for you because the `Button`  has clickable so when you click on layout and the `button` has is take the height of your layout so when click on layout the click event will respond for `Button` instead of the layout and you don't have  listener for `Button` click event no animation occurred , so you may put this in your xml layout

```
android:clickable="false"
```

this will make the event respond for layout directly  or making the animation on `Button` itself like that

```
 final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        final LinearLayout images = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.images);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //flip(image1, image2, animLength.getProgress());
                final ObjectAnimator goneToVisible = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn, "rotationY", -90f, 0f);
                goneToVisible.setDuration(1000);
                goneToVisible.start();
            }
        });
```

feed me back

Comment: It would be more helpful to the OP and future visitors to describe the changes you made and *why* they worked instead of just posing code.

Comment: Hi. if you click on the button it works ok, but if you click on the container it doesnt work with buttons inside but it works if you have ImageVies instead Buttons.   final LinearLayout images = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.images);
        images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   . I want to click on the container in order to start the animation of the button inside. Thanks

Comment: @codeMagic thanks for your comment i will explain in more details this issue

Comment: @JosePerez take look on edited answer i will explain the issue for you

Comment: @JosePerez you may also need to see [OnInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) not sure if that will do anything for you here or not

Comment: @codeMagic the problem in his code he make the button width and height like layout so he will need to disable button click  or re size its button width and height

Comment: @mohammedmomn I understand that but then the `Button`s aren't `clickable`, which is what is happening. They may be able to use that `listener` to intercept the events to decide to show the `animation`, if the `Linearlayout` was clicked or take action accordingly if it was a `Button` which was clicked.

Comment: yes if button has event listener it will be respond for button

Comment: Great. It wors now if you put clicable = "false" in button xml. Thats the reason.  Thanks a lot mohammed.